# Extract id of the div using selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

Can someone help me to extract the id text (the underline one in the below-attached image) from this link: https://opennem.org.au/facilities/au/?selected=DEIBDL&status=operating,committed,commissioning,retired

To get the right on the item in any of the items in the table and inspect.

[image]

I knew how to extract the table text but I want the id text which I underlined

Answer (score 1):

The selected element can be located by this XPath

```
//div[@class='card is-selected']
```

Or this CSS Selector

```
div.is-selected
```

So, you can use this Selenium code to extract the `id` attribute value:

```py
id = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='card is-selected']").get_attribute("id")
```

But this will give you the id appearing on the dev tools, this is not always the text you see as a user on the page.
To get the text user sees you will need this:

```py
name = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.is-selected .station-name").text
```

This can be done woth XPath as well